# Database structure constants

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I joined this new project that is using MongoDB, and I saw this structure:

collection: Users

```
salutation (ObjectId)   name (String)   status (ObjectId)
ObjectId("111")         Mark            ObjectId("112")
```

collection: Values

```
_id               description (String)
ObjectId("111")   Mr.
ObjectId("112")   active
```

For all the values that are not changeable, they are referring to the id of the Values collection. I don't know if it's a common practice in the relational data bases, but I haven't seen it in MongoDB so far.

They use Nestjs and Mongoose.

For each request they need to query Users collection and multiple times Values collection. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please avoid the use of a Values collection, which is not a good standard in mongo. If you want a list of valid salutation values you can create a Salutation Collection and so on.

Nevertheless, all will depend on the use case. Sometimes you will be able to nest attributes and sometimes you will need to have a different collection and point to that new collection with an object id.

You can read about all the mongo design patterns and every use case here:  https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-a-summary

I feel that in this case, you should nest the values of the user in the user collection and that will be fine

You can have something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Derek",
  "status": "active",
  "salutation": "Mr."
}
```

If not you will need to do lookups in a way to get the values and that will not have a good performance.